# Visual Studio 2012 new install crashes on debug

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I just re-installed Windows 8, and with it Visual Studio 2012. I opened up my solution as normal, made 2 lines change, and hit F5. The build was successful, but when launching into debug mode, I got "Visual Studio 2012 has stopped working". I have no idea why this is happening. Few things I've tried;

- Installed Update 3
- Rebooted a few times

I've got a dump of the error, and it says this;

"Tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access"

Anyone had this before?

Comment: Have you tried running as administrator?

Comment: I would probably try repairing or reinstalling Visual Studio. Also try a new blank project to see if it works, what is the solution type of your project

Comment: Maybe the update causes problems?

Comment: It was happening pre-update, too. I'm currently in the process of re-installing W8 and VS2012 again, so I'll update..

Comment: I've re-installed Windows 8, and Visual Studio 2012, and it is still happening. Both Debug and Release mode, only on Windows 8 apps. WPF, and other app types compile and run fine.